# Problem with model validation in Pytorch lightning

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, pytorch-lightning

Good evening,

I am struggling a bit with Pytorch lightning, since I am a beginner. I have this NN classifier and I have implemented the following code:

```
def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx):
    X, y = train_batch 
    y_copy = y # Integer y for the accuracy
    X = X.type(torch.float32)
    y = y.type(torch.float32)  
    # forward pass
    y_pred = self.forward(X).squeeze()  
    # accuracy
    accuracy = Accuracy()
    acc = accuracy(y_pred, y_copy)
    # compute loss
    loss = self.loss_fun(y_pred, y)
    self.log_dict({'train_loss': loss, 'train_accuracy': acc}, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss

def validation_step(self, validation_batch, batch_idx):
    X, y = validation_batch
    X = X.type(torch.float32)
    # forward pass
    y_pred = self.forward(X).squeeze()        
    # compute metrics 
    accuracy = Accuracy()
    acc = accuracy(y_pred, y)
    loss = self.loss_fun(y_pred, y)
    self.log_dict({'validation_loss': loss, 'validation_accuracy': acc}, on_step=True, on_epoch=False, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss


def test_step(self, test_batch, batch_idx):
    X, y = test_batch
    X = X.type(torch.float32)
    # forward pass
    y_pred = self.forward(X).squeeze()        
    # compute metrics   
    accuracy = Accuracy()
    acc = accuracy(y_pred, y)
    loss = self.loss_fun(y_pred, y)
    self.log_dict({'test_loss': loss, 'test_accuracy': acc}, on_epoch=False,on_step=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss
```

The main problem is visualizing and plotting the losses. The `training_step` perform some epochs and the resulted `loss` is this (in some cases):

[image]

But unfortunately, I am not able to see the validation loss/accuracy because, when I call the `validate` method (the one which calls `validation_step()`) I get only one result. Why is that ? Should the `validation_step` perform epochs also? I don't know why, I get one result and that's it.

In the following, there is the metrics logger:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question deleting `model.validate()` in the main. After this, overriding `training_step()` and `validation_step()` , when training the model, a validation loop will be executed automatically and the results will appear on the file. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is configurable, in your `validation_step` try to switch on `on_epoch=True`:

```
self.log_dict({'validation_loss': loss, 'validation_accuracy': acc}, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
```

That should give you a validation log for each epoch. See [docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/lightning_module.html#log) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried, always one result

Comment: The only way to have more results is to set a batch size and set on_step=True, but for my purpose, I have to use no batches